# Django 1.11 EmailMultiAlternatives: ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: django, python-3.x, email

Iam trying to send an email using EmailMultiAlternative. Using Django 1.11, Python 3.4. However I am getting ValueError. Am using the SMTP backend.This is the code:

```
subject = "Hi {} !".format(user.username)
sender = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
recipients = [user.email, ]
html_content = render_to_string('email/hello.html', {'url': url, 'first_name': user.first_name, 'last_name': user.last_name, 'static': HOST + settings.STATIC_URL,})
text_content = strip_tags(html_content)
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, sender, recipients)
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send().
```

However I am get the following error:

> ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Complete traceback here:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/home/george/virtuals/new_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
>      response = get_response(request)
>    File "/home/george/virtuals/new_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
>      response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>    File "/home/george/virtuals/new_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
>      response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>    File "/home/george/virtuals/new_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
>      return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>    File "/home/george/virtuals/new_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
>      return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>    File "/home/george/virtuals/new_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 183, in post
>      return self.form_valid(form)
>    File "/home/george/george/project/new_beco/applications/accounts/views.py", line 87, in form_valid
>      msg.send()
>    File "/home/george/virtuals/new_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 348, in send
>      return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
>    File "/home/george/virtuals/new_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 111, in send_messages
>      sent = self._send(message)
>    File "/home/george/virtuals/new_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 123, in _send
>      from_email = sanitize_address(email_message.from_email, encoding)
>    File "/home/george/virtuals/new_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 136, in sanitize_address
>      nm, addr = addr
>   ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: What is your `settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`?

Comment: The email from which I have to send the email('abcd@gmail.com'), which is set in the settings file

Comment: I know what the setting is for, I was asking what do you actually have in your settings file. Anonymise the username if you like, but otherwise show *exactly* what you have.

Comment: I think you could perhaps get that error if you include a comma on the end of the setting by accident, e.g. `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'abcd@gmail.com',`

Comment: No thats not the case, Checked that. What I have is email 'abcd@gmail.com'

Comment: Is that your *exact* code? I can't see how it would cause that error.

Comment: It seems so. I rechecked if the settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, but it seems to be correct.